# Major speed issues with imageWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, uiimage

In my application I'm creating a large image dynamically and then loading it up for display in my image explorer class. Because I can't add new images to the bundle at run time, it seems I have to use imageWithContentsOfFile - however, this gives me major speed issues further down the line.

The way my image explorer works is that it takes in an image, splits it up into tiles, caches those tiles and then only loads those tiles into memory for display that need to be shown on the screen. Using a bunch of NSLogs, I've managed to find out where all the slowdown is. It's not in the imageWithContentsOfFile function itself, it's when I try to call this line:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context_ref,
                   CGRectMake(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight), tileImage);
```

This is when I'm writing the tile to the cache file. tileImage is a CGImageRef that is returned from CGImageCreateWithImageInRect, which is how I get subsets of my larger image to save separately.

The odd thing is that splitting up a large image this way takes about 45 seconds (!), but when I split up an image from the bundle using imageNamed rather than imageWithContentsOfFile, it takes only about 2 seconds.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i'd *really* recommend removing all those logs and using a profiler to deduce where your time is actually spent. a bunch of logging will only slow things down, and wall clock timing is highly inaccurate for your problem.

Comment: Trust me, it's not the logs that slows it down - there is a wait of up to about 500ms on each of those draw calls I've posted above, and I make one call for each tile (there can be upwards of 200 tiles per image). When I swap to imageNamed the draw call takes a tiny fraction of that time.

Comment: my main point was not that i don't trust you, or that logs are your problem (just omit logging during profiling, and don't use logging when measuring time/speed, and don't use wall clock profiling -- esp. when superior alternatives exist). my main point is that instruments will tell you how much time is spent, and where it is spent. just compare samples using the two implementations, and your answer will likely be evident. proof and evidence beats guesswork.

Comment: Whenever you load image with imageWithContentsOfFile, all image data will be loaded into memory only when it's being drawn into context. 

To get around this, you might use getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: of ALAssetRepresentation class, I don't have any experience with it to give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think U should split up your image.
Because, CGContextDrawImage will take fully loaded "tileImage".

If your "tileImage" size is 8 MB, your app must load 8MB data to memory.
It takes long time for loading. and It may create memory issue and so on.

If you want to use a single big image and you can wait for loading,
there is solution that U can use another thread.

It can avoid to UI lock during loading a big image.

An 8MB JPG image will use over 8MB memory, UIImage should use noncompressed format for fast drawing.

Answer (score 0):

`imageNamed` uses caching, and may reduce the amount of scaling.

`UIImage` is immutable. `imageNamed` may note this and return a reference to a cached image, rather than loading and creating a new image... wherever you load your image.

if you create an images, you can setup your own (in memory) caching scheme and pass references in many cases. then purge the cache when you receive a memory warning.

if you need to scale the image and the size is static, determine the size to draw, and create a UIImage using `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` -- or you can approach the problem in a similar way using CoreGraphics apis directly too.

beyond that, hold onto/reuse what you need, and use a profiler to balance your allocations and to measure timings.